# Java Caching library with ability to expire individual elements are different times

Tags: java, caching

I am trying to build a simple caching system for caching entries from a database table, and I would like each individual entry in the Cache to have a different expiration time. Are there any Java caching libraries with the ability to set different expiration times for each individual entry in the cache?

P.S: I know REDIS does this but it is way too heavy for my use-case. Looking for something more lightweight. I looked at guava LoadingCache and EhCache. However both of these seem to have a global expiration timeout for ALL entries in the Cache. I am looking for something more fine grained.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by lightweight? Should it run embedded in your app? Stored in memory? Should the cache disappear when your app shuts down?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few months since you posted your request, but please consider [FeCache](https://bitbucket.org/ccperkins/fecache)

FeCache is an extremely lightweight simple caching library in Java which allows entries to be cached with different expiration times, specified in milliseconds - that is, each entry can be given a different time-to-live.  I hope I'm using the term correctly here: it's FOSS, licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.

I think it meets both of your requirements:

- Each individual entry in the Cache can have a different expiration time
- It is definitely more lightweight than Redis (the jar including the unit tests is 7492 bytes)

Disclaimer:  I am the author of FeCache.